# Show progress of multiple website downloads during button press

Tags: android, download, progress-bar, loading

I need to retrieve some data from roughly 50 different URLS with the press of a button.

The code goes through them one at a time, and although it doesn't take that long, it will take around 20 seconds, and I have all this code running inside of a button.

I was hoping I could update a TextView or something to say "Loading page 1 of 50" then "Loading page 2 of 50" etc, in between accessing the different websites.

The code below works, just the button gets stuck down for an unknown amount of time, and I want the user to have some indication of how far along the loading is doing.

```
btnGetData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //regionRetrieve 1 page of auction data, so we know how many future pages to retrieve. -P
                String auctionURL = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?page=";
                String firstPage = null;
                try {
                    firstPage = new RetrieveData().execute(auctionURL + "0").get();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    auctionInfo = new JSONObject(firstPage);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //endregion

                //regionRetrieve the remaining pages
                int totalPages = 0;
                try {
                    totalPages = auctionInfo.getInt("totalPages");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Place to put the rest of the pages
                ArrayList<String> remainingPages = new ArrayList<>();

                //Starts at 1, because we already retrieved the 0 page as the first page.
                //Also, I checked, and you do need to retrieve the 52nd page if there are say, 52 pages.
                for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; ++i) {
                    
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//ADD SOME KIND OF NOTIFICATION HERE
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    String newPage = null;
                    try {
                        newPage = new RetrieveData().execute(auctionURL + i).get();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    remainingPages.add(newPage);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All data received.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //endregion

                //stuff below this point is irrelevant to the question
            }
        });
```

I tried wrapping all of the code above inside an AsyncTask, and utilizing the "onProgressUpdate", but that did not work. Furthermore, I heard that by now, AsyncTask has been deprecated, and that there are better ways to do it.

I also tried using Toast messages, but they all show up at the end, which kind of defeats the purpose.

I even put the Toast messages in the AsyncTasks that I call in order to get the data, but that didn't work either. (The RetrieveData() is an AsyncTask that reads all the information from the URLS, and returns it as a String. I know you aren't supposed to use get, but in this case it is important the data arrives in the correct order. Unless, after retrieving the first one, and knowing how many pages there are, I could launch 50 threads at the same time to retrieve the data? But still, you are limited by your internet connection, and the user is still sitting there confused.)

Is there a proper way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting all the code in the button, make the button launch another activity, and put the data retrieval code in that activity.
Launch the code inside of a thread, and from within the thread, update UI elements to inform the user of the progress.
After the data is retrieved, store it, then start an Intent to go back to the previous activity, access the data where you stored it, and use it for whatever you needed to do.

(I know I answered my own question, but I figured it out a few hours later and nobody had responded up until now, hopefully this helps someone in the future.)